Why do we use the leaf of the Lulav, and not the Date?
According to the midrash, the lulav is the species that has no fragrance, but it has a good taste. That's referring to its dates, yet the Torah says we should take the leaf, and use it for the avodah, rather than the date.
Why not the date?

The dates have taste and smell. They are not as perfect in appearance as compared to esrog, but that would disqualify the bundle representative of 4 groups of Jewish people!

@YDJ so the midrash is wrong? Or?

The midrash works, it is speaking about lulav, not the dates. I made the comment as a way of proof by contradiction. It often does not work because the logic of gemara is not binary. It is not math. Very good question.

The pasuk specifies the leaf

The question can be further generalized, why the lulav bundle has only branches instead of the fruit of the plants?
When looking at the question this way, one can recall the verse Devarim 20:19

כִּֽי־תָצ֣וּר אֶל־עִיר֩ יָמִ֨ים רַבִּ֜ים לְֽהִלָּחֵ֧ם עָלֶ֣יהָ לְתׇפְשָׂ֗הּ לֹֽא־תַשְׁחִ֤ית אֶת־עֵצָהּ֙ לִנְדֹּ֤חַ עָלָיו֙ גַּרְזֶ֔ן כִּ֚י מִמֶּ֣נּוּ תֹאכֵ֔ל וְאֹת֖וֹ לֹ֣א תִכְרֹ֑ת כִּ֤י הָֽאָדָם֙ עֵ֣ץ הַשָּׂדֶ֔ה לָבֹ֥א מִפָּנֶ֖יךָ בַּמָּצֽוֹר׃

The bold letters are translated  because a man is a tree of the field. If a man is like a tree, and its fruit are mitzvos, then the branches are man's efforts to fulfill mitzvos. (1)
Thus, the plants in the lulav bundle can symbolize our efforts in achieving the perfect mitzva (fruit). Perhaps, that is a reason for the mitzvah of shaking in all directions - to seek all possible efforts, as these directions also symbolize 7 physical sefiros (right - chesed, left - gevura, front - tiferes, up - netzach, down - hod, back - yesod, center - malchus, see The Four Species by R' DovBer Pinson). Also, one can connect this idea to the well-known midrash Vayikra Rabba 30:12

Another matter: “The fruit of a pleasant [hadar] tree” – this is Israel; just as the citron has taste and has fragrance, so Israel has people among them who have Torah and have good deeds. “Branches of date palms” – this is Israel; just as the date palm has taste but has no fragrance, so Israel has people among them who have Torah but do not have good deeds. “A bough of a leafy tree” – this is Israel; just as the myrtle has fragrance but has no taste, so Israel has people among them who have good deeds but do not have Torah. “Willows of the brook” – this is Israel; just as the willow has no taste and has no fragrance, so Israel has people among them who do not have Torah and do not have good deeds. What does the Holy One blessed be He do to them? To eradicate them is not possible. Rather, the Holy One blessed be He said: Let them all be bound together in a single bundle and they will atone for one another. If you do so, at that moment, I will be ascendant [mitaleh]. That is what is written: “Who built His upper chamber [maalotav] in the heavens” (Amos 9:6). When is He ascendant? When they are made into a single group, as it is stated: “And established His group upon earth” (Amos 9:6). Therefore, Moses exhorts Israel and says to them: “You shall take for you on the first day.”

One can interpret the categories of people, who either have knowledge of Torah, or have good deeds, or neither as applied to own efforts in learning Torah, doing good deeds or just plain physical acts - all tied to perform each and one single mitzva symbolized by a separately placed esrog.
Incidentally, it also answers the question, why esrog is one. When a person performs a mitzvah, s/he is exempt from other mitzvos. Esrog is like a heart, hinting that one's heart must be full with performing the mitzvah.
Also it ties well with the question why we make the blessing on lulav as lulav symbolizes the Torah knowledge, our guidance in performing the mitzvah (hence it is the tallest).

(1) Perhaps, these analogies are also at play in the story of Adam and Chava in Gan Eden and their self-imposed stringency not to touch the tree of knowledge of good and evil (Bereshis Rabba 19:3). Since the Gan was a spiritual place, its trees and their branches symbolized efforts to do mitzvos, and the mitzvos themselves were the fruit of the garden trees.

I got an answer from a sicha from the Lubavitcher Rebbe, as well as a few other sources. I wrote it as a dvar Torah, along with other sources and my own structure and delivered it on Sukkot 1 morning. This is the dvar Torah:
Sukkot 5785
There is a famous midrash, midrash Rabba in Vayikra, that discusses the inner meaning of the arba minim. The etrog has a good fragrance and taste, and represents Jews who have Torah and Mitzvot. The lulav has a good taste, but no smell, and represents Jews who have Torah, but not Mitzvot. The Haddasim have a good fragrance, but no good taste, representing Jews who have Mitzvot but not Torah, and finally, for the rest of us, there is the Aravot, which have neither a good taste or a good fragrance, and represent us Jews deficient in Torah and Mitzvot. Nonetheless, Hashem sees us all as one, and we are all equally precious before Him. This was concealed in Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur – we all had one mitzva that is for all of us – listening to the Shofar. Now on Succot, we have a Mitzva that reveals the differences between us, but nonetheless we are instructed to bind the species together and thus show that we can be all one despite our differences.
There are two questions I wish to ask. Firstly, it seems clear that the Etrog is the most superior of the minim, as it has Torah and Mitzvot, yet the bracha is “Al Netilat Lulav”, not Etrog!
Secondly, the point about the lulav is that it has a good taste. That’s referring to its fruit – the dates, rather than the leaf, which is what the Torah tells us to take. Why doesn’t the Torah tell us to take the dates?
Regarding the first question, the gemara tells us that we take the lulav because it is taller than the rest. What’s that got to do with anything? We have to understand that even though it says this is a person who has Torah and not Mitzvot, it doesn’t mean that it is discussing a person who has literally no Mitzvot. Someone who studies but does not perform is described as wicked! It means that this person dedicates themselves to Torah, in order to perform Mitzvot – they put Torah study as paramount.
As such, they are able to connect to Hashem more closely. This is because the Torah is described as totally united with Hashem. As it says in Gemara Shabbat, when Hashem gave the Torah, He opened with the word “Anochi”. This interesting choice of word, instead of Ani, was chosen because it is an acronym: “Ana Nafshit Ketovit Yehovit” – I put My soul in writing and gave it to you. The Torah is Hashem revealing Himself to us, and by learning it, we connect to His Wisdom.
This is why the Ben Yehoyada describes the Lulav as representative of the Tzaddik. He learns Torah as paramount, but all in order to perform its Mitzvot. We are all bound to the Tzaddik, and through the Tzaddik, our Mitzvot and connection to Hashem are established and draw down Hashem’s blessings and love.
The connection we have to Hashem through Mitzvot is very powerful, but it is not as powerful as through Torah. The Mitzvot are described in the Zohar as the limbs of the King. Just as the limbs of the body are not one with the soul—they are, however, nullified to the soul and fulfill its will automatically as soon as the soul desires—they are nevertheless not the soul itself. So too, the performance of mitzvot reflects a person's submission and nullification to G-d, as he fulfills the Divine will. However, the individual performing the mitzvot still retains their own independent existence and is not, so to speak, unified with the Creator.
Now we have a basis to understand the concept of waving the Lulav. The Ben Ish Chai explains how the waving corresponds to Hashem’s name, YKVK, indicating that just as this Name represents that Hashem is everywhere, so too we wave the Lulav in all directions to show that we, through our learning, recognise that Hashem‘s dominion is absolute. Not only that, but he says in Ben Yehoyada that by waving the lulav, we are expressing our yearning for Hashem, and this is met with His yearning for us, and thus we create a unity between Him and us, which is possible because of the unity we have amongst ourselves, as indicated by the binding of the four species.
On top of this, it corresponds to the swaying that we engage in when we learn. The Zohar explains that the reason we sway while we learn is because the soul of man is the candle of Hashem. Just as a candle flickers because it is drawn upwards, so too the soul tries to unite with Hashem through Torah and Mitzvot.
The soul in heaven is described as standing still, as until we come down into a physical body, we cannot progress or grow. But when we come down, not only can we grow, we have unlimited potential for growth. The essential growth is through Torah, because, as we said, it connects us to Hashem in a perfect unity, even more so than the performance of Mitzvot, and that’s why it is the lulav that has the mitzva of swaying, specifically.
This brings us back to the question – why do we shake the lulav, which is the leaf of the date palm, and not the date?
The reason why there is a concept of swaying in Torah learning is because, in order to progress in our studies, we must go through a process of shak[la] vetariya. That is, we ask a question, we give an answer, we ask a question on that answer, and we have to go through this process – of constantly refining, making mistakes, improving, and making more mistakes.
Let me illustrate this with a story. A father once came to the Alter Rebbe and said, my son is very brilliant, and I thank you for letting him in your yeshiva – he is doing very well. The only issue I have with him is that it is all going to his head, he’s become arrogant. So the Alter Rebbe said, bring him to me. So the father brought him, and the Rebbe asked him a question on a gemara. The Rebbe then said, is it a good question? The bochur said yes. The Rebbe said no it isn’t! And gave a seemingly obvious answer. Then he asked him, is that a good answer? The boy said again yes, and the Rebbe said “no it isn’t!” and proceeded to ask a seemingly obvious kashe on the answer. So, is it a good kashe? The boy said yes, and he said no it isn’t! This went on another half dozen times, until the Rebbe turned to the boy, and said nu, I thought you said he was clever? The boy was taken down a notch, to say the least.
When it comes to learning, we are meant to approach it with humility and bittul. This is because, even though indeed the Torah does contain all the secrets of life, those secrets are lofty, truly infinite in their beauty and sweetness. All our learning is constantly going towards this beauty, but it is a lifetimes work.
This is why we don’t shake the date. The real pleasure in learning comes at the end, when we have the answer ("the ultimate pleasure is the resolution of doubts"). This is a lifetime’s work, and a reward for the future. For now, Torah study isn’t necessarily as pleasurable as it should be. Indeed Shak’vetariya, and pilpul can be quite frustrating. Nonetheless, this gives us an opportunity to engage in some real bittul. This bittul is what enables all Jews to come together. Even though we are very different, we don’t need to worry, we can still be united, if we can get our egos out of the way, and learn some humility, so indeed the ikar species is the lulav – Torah study, the closeness we get with Hashem, and the humility that enables us to get close to eachother.

Let me know if you want any specific sources for my references
